# Angular, store only the date using myDatePicker (without epoc part)

Tags: angular, typescript

I need help to format a date input into `yyyy-mm-dd` when the form is submitted. I'm using [myDatePicker](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) package. Here is myDatepicker live [demo](http://kekeh.github.io/mydatepicker/). In the right side we can see there is a field looks like this `Formatted: 01 Jan 2018 - epoc: 1514739600` when we pick a date (1st Jan of 2018), that's how the format by default. I just need to store the `formatted` part like the `DD MMM YYYY` part without the `epoc xxx` part.

```js
form01: FormGroup;
public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
};

setDate(): void {
  let date = new Date();
  this.form01.patchValue({
    DoB: {
      date: {
        year: date.getFullYear(),
        month: date.getMonth() + 1,
        day: date.getDate()
      }
    },
    DateSubmit: {
      date: {
        year: date.getFullYear(),
        month: date.getMonth() + 1,
        day: date.getDate()
      }
    }
  });
}

clearDate(): void {
  this.form01.patchValue({
    DoB: null,
    DateSubmit: null
  });
}

constructor(public builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form01s = this.builder.group({
      DoB: [null, Validators.required],
      DateSubmit: [null, Validators.required]
    })

    pushForm01() {
      console.log(this.form01.controls.DoB.value);
      console.log(this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value);
    }
```

Here is what the `console.log` shows me `{date: {…}, jsdate: Sun Jan 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time), formatted: "28/01/2018", epoc: 1517072400}`.
I need to store the format into `yyyy-mm-dd` without the other part. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What are you getting from the `console.log`?

Comment: `{date: {…}, jsdate: Sun Jan 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time), formatted: "28/01/2018", epoc: 1517072400}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your object the date object will have day,month,year you just need format them to get the result in `yyyy-mm-dd`

im considering `this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value` contains the object which have posted in the comment

try this

```
var month = (this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.month > 9) ? this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.month : "0"+ this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.month;
var day = (this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.month > 9) ? this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.day : "0"+ this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.day;


console.log(this.form01.controls.DateSubmit.value.date.year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
```